# Why is twiddle wakka designed like this?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, versioning

In the twiddle wakka `~>` (aka pessimistic operator), why is it designed so that the tidle comes before the inequality? Since it includes the meaning `>=`, it is more consistent if it were `>~`. The `~>` order makes it difficult to remember, and I often mistype it `>~`. It also makes me feel incorrectly that `~> 3.2` does not allow exactly `3.2`. Is there a precursor to this symbol, or was it made up by a gem developer? Can someone come up with a way to make sense of this (even if that is not the original intention)?

Comment: Well, it looks a bit like a twiddly hash rocket (and thus kinda like an assignment), doesn't it?

Comment: @HolgerJust It does, but why assignment? It is a condition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jim Weirich originally added the pessimistic operator to RubyGems as `>*` [in this commit](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/eacba214b5d815e82d0ab0c09a7ac378e004898e). He then changed it to `~>` [a few weeks later](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/b9d09b19571b6b884fba3384c98f41acd4c5e755) - the commit message includes an explanation:

> Changed the pessimistic operator to "~>" (think approximately greater than).

Personally, I like that `~>` is visually distinct from `>=`; if the operator was `>~` instead, I think it would be easier to misread as `>=` when glancing at a Gemfile.